# Разделить строку на слова в c++

Tags: c++, строки

Доброго времени суток!

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int f1(char str[], int n);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    int kil;
    int n = 20;
    char str1[200];
    cout << "input string ";
    gets_s(str1);
    cout << str1;
    int num;
    char *s1 = str1;
    kil = f1(str1, num);
}


int f1(char str[], int n)
{
    char *a = new char[n];
    int  k = 0; //
    char del[] = "., "; 
    int *delimiter;
    delimiter = del[];
    char *p;
    cout << "List of words: " << endl;
    p = strtok(str, delimiter);
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(a, p);
        cout << p;
        k++;
        p = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }
    cout << "number of words = " << k << endl;
    return k;
}
```

Мне нужно из заданной строки найти и удалить слова, которые заканчиваются группой из 3 введенных символов. У меня возникает проблема в том, что я введенною строку хочу разделить на слова, но у мене ошибка с разделителем. Помогите исправить ошибку, пожалуйста. Большое спасибо!

Comment: `int *delimiter; delimiter = del[];` - что это за махинации?